# Arch/Plasma - PolicyKit window not opening for Virtual Machine Manager;

Tags: arch-linux, kde, kde-plasma-5, virt-manager, policykit

I'm relatively new to linux and I have using Arch linux as the host for some virtual machines for some time now. I don't know what triggered it, but lately 90% of the times I boot and open the Virtual Machine Manager window, the PolicyKit window that used to pop up to authenticate me doesn't pop up, leaving the Virtual Manager window on "Connecting..." and never loading the VMs. Doesn't matter what I do, nothing seems to fix it, only rebooting and hoping I'm in the 10% this time.

Does anybody know why this happens and how to fix it?

I have no idea what info to share here that would be helpful to fix this so if you need any just ask me and I'll add to the post.

**versions:**

```
$ uname -srm
Linux 6.2.13-arch1-1-vfio x86_64

$ plasmashell --version
plasmashell 5.27.5

$ kf5-config --version
Qt: 5.15.9
KDE Frameworks: 5.106.0
kf5-config: 1.0

$ virt-manager --version
4.1.0

$ pacman -Q polkit-kde-agent
polkit-kde-agent 5.27.5-1
```

**EDIT #1:**

```
● polkit.service - Authorization Manager
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/polkit.service; static)
    Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-06-14 13:15:14 -03; 2h 44min ago
    Docs: man:polkit(8)
Main PID: 1593 (polkitd)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 38244)
    Memory: 6.1M
        CPU: 348ms
    CGroup: /system.slice/polkit.service
            └─1593 /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd --no-debug

Jun 14 13:15:14 archlinux systemd[1]: Starting Authorization Manager...
Jun 14 13:15:14 archlinux polkitd[1593]: Started polkitd version 122
Jun 14 13:15:14 archlinux polkitd[1593]: Loading rules from directory /etc/polkit-1/rules.d
Jun 14 13:15:14 archlinux polkitd[1593]: Loading rules from directory /usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d
Jun 14 13:15:14 archlinux polkitd[1593]: Finished loading, compiling and executing 7 rules
Jun 14 13:15:14 archlinux systemd[1]: Started Authorization Manager.
Jun 14 13:15:14 archlinux polkitd[1593]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 on the system bus
Jun 14 13:15:17 archlinux polkitd[1593]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:4 (system bus name :1.41 [/usr/lib/polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/kde/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale C.UTF-8)
```

On the `polkit.service` logs, there is an extra log on successful (10%ers) sessions, right after the "Registered Authentication Agent" log:

```
Jun 14 12:59:43 archlinux polkitd[1157]: Operator of unix-session:2 successfully authenticated as unix-user:MYUSER to gain TEMPORARY authorization for action org.libvirt.unix.manage for unix-process:2010:18511 [/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/virt-manager] (owned by unix-user:MYUSER)
```

Answer (score 0):

After much research I found that simply restarting `libvirtd` does the trick:

```
$ systemctl restart libvirtd
```